# Django application running inside of a container but cannoct resolve DB outside of it

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django application which I've decided to setup in container as follows:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

with database config in settings as follows

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

And when I run the containers, the app works correctly with me being able to migrate and insert data into database.

However when I try to run the project outside of the container by following steps:

1. `python -m venv venv`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`
3. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. `python manage.py runserver`

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 576, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 243, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/jdoni/code/work/tasks/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I don't really understand why django is unable to recognize the database host outside of container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Django setup, I'd use an environment variable to specify the database location.  You can set a default value for it, and I'd generally use a developer-friendly default.

```py
DATABASES = {
  "default": {
    "HOST": os.getenv("PGHOST", "localhost"),
    ...
  }
}
```

So long as your database container publishes `ports:`, you can use this with a host-based development setup

```bash
docker-compose up -d db

. ./venv/bin/activate
./manage.py runserver
```

This means you need to set the environment variable in your Compose setup as well.

```yaml
version: '3.8'  # most recent 3.x Compose file version
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:   # add
      PGHOST: db   # add
    # (should not need volumes: or command: override)

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    ports:            # add
      - '5432:5432'   # add

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

If your host system is already using port 5432 for a different database, you need to change the *first* `ports:` number to something else that doesn't conflict; the second must be fixed at the standard port 5432.  You also will need to make the database port number configurable in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the "db" container available locally, just map a local port, like this:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

now you can check connection with:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432
```

to access it from Django locally, you need to change a config to:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "localhost",   # <----- HERE IS THE CHANGE
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. Is there a way to set the HOST name to both 'db' and 'localhost' for the run? I came to this issue because I have a tox.ini file that runs the tests for database but is not able to resolve the host name when it is set to DB..